# LINQ to SQL: how to set a caption for columns(alias) of table in Lambda Express 

Tags: sql, ssms, caption

I use the SQL Management Studio for create database
I create a table and create columns of table
Names of columns are on the English language like "test_ID"

in the server side when  run a query(linq to sql)  and got the dataTable result
server send  that dataTable to client side

In the side client, I set the dataTable to a DataGridView
When  DataGridView show that table, caption  columns are same names columns  that I create in the SQL  management for my table

but I want show a another text(caption ) for columns with another language (for example my column name is “Test_Id” but a caption text for column that i want show to the DGV is “شمارنده”  In the Farsi language)

and I don’t set text Columns(or caption ) in the client side, I want set a label text(caption ) for all columns in the SQL management.

in the T-SQL  under syntax is true

```
select yourFirstColumn as TheColumnNameYouWant1, yourSecondColumn as TheColumnNameYouWant2
from yourTable
```

but i whant a Answer In the linq express (Lambda express)
like sample code:

```
var obj2 = GP.TestTables.Select(x => new {  x.name  });
```

i can alias column like this

```
var obj2 = GP.TestTables.Select(x => new {  **alias1** = x.name  });
```

but Without combine works  sample

```
var obj2 = GP.TestTables.Select(x => new { ***name of company*** =  x.name  });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't try to do this in SQL.  Display considerations should be kept separate from data storage, retrieval and processing. The alternative is to tie your databases hands with display issues, making for inflexible and fragile builds.  When you pull your data into a dataset you can play with the column names to your heart's content, and the database need never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use column aliases to set the field names in your queries like so:

```
select yourFirstColumn as TheColumnNameYouWant1, yourSecondColumn as TheColumnNameYouWant2
from yourTable
```